# How to split a list of vectors into columns or matrix?

Tags: r, regex, data-conversion, mapply

I've got a list of vectors that take this form:

```
> g
[[1]]
 [1] "L"  "14" "L"  "39" "L"  "61" "B"  "0"  "L"  "15" "L"  "59" "W"  "64"

[[2]]
[1] "L"  "62" "D"  "31" "L"  "10" "L"  "30" "B"  "0"  "D"  "45" "L"  "43"

[[3]]
 [1] "H"  "0"  "L"  "11" "L"  "35" "W"  "45" "H"  "0"  "L"  "40" "L"  "42"
```

My goal is to use `mapply` on this structure and turn each of the 14 columns into a vector.  The first column would be:

```
[[1]]
[1] "L"

[[2]]
[1] "L"

[[3]]
[1] "H"
```

And the second column would be:

```
[[1]]
[1] "14"

[[2]]
[1] "62"

[[3]]
[1] "0"
```

and so on.  I suspect the structure would be a matrix (?) but I'm not sure.  I used a lot of `lapply` and `stringr`'s `str_extract_all` with regex to get this point but I am unsure how to proceed.  I suspect the function would use a pattern like: `"[A-Z]{1}"` for the text and `"[:digit:]{1}"` and I know that `mapply` can return a matrix but I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Using regexs here makes no sense. Perhaps it would be helpful to explain where this data is coming from (e.g., csv file, web scrape, manually-entered) and how you need to use it (e.g., plot it with `pkg::xyz()`). (And for clarity: your first block is a simple `list`, where each element is a `character` vector (not list). Your second and third blocks are both the same: a simple `list`, each element is a `character` vector (of length 1).

Comment: I don't know R - but I agree with @r2evans regex seems overkill here, a quick bit of googling lead me to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464312/convert-comma-separated-entry-to-columns which seems like it's fairly close, but I'm not going to pretend I know R and try and change to suit your scenario exactly.

Comment: It's one small part of a much larger set of patterns that are taking apart a file - this is just one section of it. I'm basically looking for the `function` that outputs the this as a matrix or a series of lists.

Comment: There was a comment (since deleted) that suggested `do.call(rbind, g)`. It turns this `g` into a neat `matrix`. But you say you want each of the columns as a vector, so something like `lapply(seq_along(g[[1]]), function(i) sapply(g, `[[`, i))` gives that, but then you mention *"return a matrix"*, so I am very confused between what you say, what you need, and what you describe.

Comment: apologies - I am still working out how these structures are described.  I could probably work with either a matrix or a list: It seems like  `do.call(rbind, g)` also worked perfectly and appears to be the same structure, too.  I'll have to read up on `do.call(rbind, ...)` - Thank you!

Comment: See, also, a similar post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164803/fastest-way-to-transpose-a-list-in-r-rcpp)

Comment: you could do g %>% unlist(use.names = F) %>% matrix(nrow = 14) %>% t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using mapply

```
g <- list()
g[[1]] <- c("L",  "14", "L",  "39", "L",  "61", "B",  "0",  "L",  "15", "L",  "59", "W",  "64")
g[[2]] <- c("L",  "62", "D",  "31", "L",  "10", "L",  "30", "B",  "0",  "D",  "45", "L",  "43")
g[[3]] <- c("H",  "0",  "L",  "11", "L",  "35", "W",  "45", "H",  "0",  "L",  "40", "L",  "42")
```

Consider simple case where you want to extract first element in each list element, you can use lapply:

```
lapply(g, function (x) x[1])
```

Now we can use mapply to iterate:

```
lengths(g) # returns length of each element in the list
g2 <- mapply(function(y) lapply(g, function (x) x[y]), 1:lengths(g)[1])
g2

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
# [1,] "L"  "14" "L"  "39" "L"  "61" "B"  "0"  "L"  "15"  "L"   "59"  "W"   "64" 
# [2,] "L"  "62" "D"  "31" "L"  "10" "L"  "30" "B"  "0"   "D"   "45"  "L"   "43" 
# [3,] "H"  "0"  "L"  "11" "L"  "35" "W"  "45" "H"  "0"   "L"   "40"  "L"   "42" 

g2[,1]
# [[1]]
# [1] "L"

# [[2]]
# [1] "L"

# [[3]]
# [1] "H"

unlist(g2[,1])
# [1] "L" "L" "H"
```

Comment: `do.call(rbind, g)` gets to the matrix a little shorter/faster (copied from another comment, since deleted).

Comment: _this_ is it, dude! Thank you! `lengths()` will come in handy.  Quick follow-up: the form: `function (x) x[1]` in `lapply(g, function (x) x[1])` would that be the same as: `function (x){ x[1]}`?

Comment: good call of do.call r2evans, I forgot about that.  @jmb277, {} allows you to group statements, allowing you to place multiple statements within the function body.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative to `do.call(rbind, g)`, we can use the fact that a data.frame actually is a list of vectors where all vectors have the same lengths. So, the given structure `g`can be converted to a data.frame which is then transposed yielding a matrix as requested.

**Reproduce the data:**

```
g <- list(
  c("L",  "14", "L",  "39", "L",  "61", "B",  "0",  "L",  "15", "L",  "59", "W",  "64"),
  c("L",  "62", "D",  "31", "L",  "10", "L",  "30", "B",  "0",  "D",  "45", "L",  "43"),
  c("H",  "0",  "L",  "11", "L",  "35", "W",  "45", "H",  "0",  "L",  "40", "L",  "42")
)
```

**Transform:**

```
m <- t(as.data.frame(g))
dimnames(m) <- NULL   # remove deafault row names
m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
#[1,] "L"  "14" "L"  "39" "L"  "61" "B"  "0"  "L"  "15"  "L"   "59"  "W"   "64" 
#[2,] "L"  "62" "D"  "31" "L"  "10" "L"  "30" "B"  "0"   "D"   "45"  "L"   "43" 
#[3,] "H"  "0"  "L"  "11" "L"  "35" "W"  "45" "H"  "0"   "L"   "40"  "L"   "42"
```

**Access the columns:**

```
m[, 1]
#[1] "L" "L" "H"
```

Comment: This is also a fantastic answer that works great! I'll have to read up on `do.call` as the help section is pretty general!