# Dispatch values in list column to separate columns

Tags: r, list, data.table

I have a data.table with a `list` column "c":

```
df <- data.table(a = 1:3, c = list(1L, 1:2, 1:3))
df
   a     c
1: 1     1
2: 2   1,2
3: 3 1,2,3
```

I want to create separate columns for the values in "c".

I create a set of new columns F_1, F_2, F_3:

```
mmax <- max(df$a)
flux <- paste("F", 1:mmax, sep = "_")
df[, (flux) := 0]

df
   a     c F_1 F_2 F_3
1: 1     1   0   0   0
2: 2   1,2   0   0   0
3: 3 1,2,3   0   0   0
```

I want to dispatch values in "c" to columns F_1, F_2, F_3 like this:

```
df

   a     c F_1 F_2 F_3
1: 1     1   1   0   0
2: 2   1,2   1   2   0
3: 3 1,2,3   1   2   3
```

What I have tried:

```
comp_vect <- function(vec, mmax){
  vec   <- vec %>% unlist()
  n     <- length(vec)
  answr <- c(vec, rep(0, l = mmax -n)) 
}


df[ , ..flux := mapply(comp_vect, c, mmax)]
```

The expected data.table is :

```
> df

   a     c F_1 F_2 F_3
1: 1     1   1   0   0
2: 2   1,2   1   2   0
3: 3 1,2,3   1   2   3
```

Comment: `d[ , (cols) := transpose(c,  fill = 0)]`

Comment: See also: [How to flatten R data frame that contains lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34206003/how-to-flatten-r-data-frame-that-contains-lists); [Fastest way to transpose a list in R / Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164803/fastest-way-to-transpose-a-list-in-r-rcpp)

Comment: @Henrik shouldn't you post this as the answer? `df[, paste("F_", 1:3) := transpose(d, fill = 0L)]`

Comment: You could also use `lengths` to determine the number of column names to be created; `paste0("f_", seq_len(max(lengths(df$c))))`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution** :

```
for(idx in seq(max(sapply(df$c, length)))){  # maximum number of values according to all the elements of the list
  set(x = df,
      i = NULL,
      j = paste0("F_",idx),  # column's name
      value = sapply(df$c, function(x){
        if(is.na(x[idx])){
          return(0)  # 0 instead of NA
        } else {
          return(x[idx])
        }
      })
  )
}
```

**Explications** :

We can extract the values from a list like this :

```
sapply(df$c, function(ll) return(ll[1])) # first value
[1] 1 1 1
sapply(df$c, function(ll) return(ll[2])) # second value
[1] NA  2  2
sapply(df$c, function(ll) return(ll[3])) # third value
[1] NA NA  3
```

We see that if there is no value, we have a `NA`.
We need an iterator to extract all values at the position `idx`. For that, we'll find the number of values in each element of `df$c` (the list) and keep the maximum.

```
max(sapply(df$c, length))
[1] 3
```

If we want zeros instead of `NAs`, we need to create a function in the sapply to convert them :

```
vec <- c(NA, 5, 1, NA)
> sapply(vec, function(x) if(is.na(x)) return(0) else return(x))
[1] 0 5 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed a radically different approach. I `rbind`ed the list column and then `dcast`ed it, obtaining the desired result. Last part is to set the names.

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(a = 1:3, d = list(1L, c(1L, 2L), c(1L, 2L, 3L)))

df2 <- df[, rbind(d), by = a][, dcast(.SD, a ~ V1, fill = 0)]

setnames(df2, 2:4, flux)[]
   a F_1 F_2 F_3
1: 1   1   0   0
2: 2   1   2   0
3: 3   1   2   3
```

where `flux` is the variable of names that you defined in your question.

Please notice that avoided using the column name `c`, as it may be confused with the function `c()`.