# "invert" the organisation of a list

Tags: r

Is there an easy way to "invert" the organisation of a list from, say

```
list(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))

[[1]]
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

to

```
[[1]]
[1]  TRUE  FALSE

[[2]]
[1] TRUE FALSE

[[3]]
[1] FALSE FALSE
```

?

I'm working with an *lapply* command that returns a list organised in a way that's very inconvenient. I didn't manage to turn around the arguments in the *lapply* command so it produces a list in a way I can further process.

Comment: Try: `do.call(Map, c(c, lst))` if `lst` is the name of your list...

Comment: A write up as answer, with elucidation of `c(c` construct would be appreciated, as it performs exactly as OP desired.

Comment: If you are happy to use non-`base`: `data.table::transpose`. See e.g. [Fastest way to transpose a list in R / Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164803/fastest-way-to-transpose-a-list-in-r-rcpp)

Comment: Sorry @Chris - I was going to post an answer but see it is closed (and understandably so - there are other answers that do address this already, I agree with Henrik). If there was sufficient interest in a greater explanation and it was reopened, I would be happy to share an answer. (But again, I'm totally fine either way!).